# Submitting form with values containing special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

```
$('form').on('submit', function(submitEvent)
{
    $('table[id*=OtherOptions] :input').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#collapsiblePanel :input').attr('disabled', false);

    if (preventSubmit)
    {
        submitEvent.preventDefault();

        populateDateValues();

        populateContextFilterValues();

        if($.browser.msie)
        {
                $('#collapsiblePanelHiddenValues').val(JSON.stringify(collapsiblePanelObj));
        }

        var form = $(this);

        var formInput = decodeURIComponent(form.serialize());           

        $.getJSON('ValidateParams', formInput, function(data)
        { 
// Some more code here...
```

In the above code i am making the validation call to a struts2 action with the form data but if some form field contains # or % as value then while getting the request parameters on the server side all the parameters after these special characters do not come in the request parameter map.

What could be the solution to the above problem?

Comment: Are you sure about your intention to `decodeURIComponent` before you send the form input? I'm pretty sure that your intention should be to encodeURIComponent for sending. Check out [this site](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/) and see what it produces.

Comment: If i send the form input this way then on the server side i get a request parameter map with key as the parameter name and value as its value but if I use encodeURIComponent then I get only one string value in the map with all the characters encoded. That's not what i am want, i want it to come as a map of key values of parameters. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by not calling the decodeURIComponent and only sending the serialized form data to server side where the encoded data is automatically decoded by struts2.

Comment: Ahh...I wondered why that was a necessary step for you. Glad you got your answer. You should post your comment as an answer and then accept it to round out this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by not calling the decodeURIComponent and only sending the serialized form data to server side where the encoded data is automatically decoded by struts2.